# Почему не нажимается right arrow?

Tags: javascript

```
function test() { 
if (!document.getElementById('monster-1')) {
var m1 = new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'keyCode':37,'which':37});
document.dispatchEvent(m1);
} else if (!document.getElementById('monster-2')) {
var m2 = new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'keyCode':39,'which':39}); 
document.dispatchEvent(m2); 
} else { 
var m3 = new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'keyCode':40,'which':40});
document.dispatchEvent(m3);
}
};
setInterval( test, 1000 );
```

left arrow - работает

right arrow и down arrow - не работают

Comment: можно код с HTML и в сниппете офрмленные, чтобы можно было запустить и посмотреть?

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю логики, но не срабатывает так как у вас условие `else if`, то есть вы проверяете условие, там получаете `true` и дальше по функции не идете. Вот можете попробовать добавляя или убирая искомый элемент на странице.

```js
function test() { 
if (!document.getElementById('monster-1')) {
var m1 = new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'keyCode':37,'which':37});
document.dispatchEvent(m1);
  console.log("left arrow");
}  
  if (!document.getElementById('monster-2')) {
var m2 = new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'keyCode':39,'which':39}); 
document.dispatchEvent(m2); 
  console.log("right arrow");
} else { 
var m3 = new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'keyCode':40,'which':40});
document.dispatchEvent(m3);
  console.log("down arrow");
}
};

test();
```